# Python Union Types with Objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-annotation

I am writing my own classes for int, str, bool, etc. that have generators on them. I am using this to fuzz the function based on the type annotations. This is going fine, with the exception of the `|` notation for union type. If I type something like:

```
def test_handles_none_with_arged_types(
    x: Int[0, 10] | List[Int] | Str | Dict[NoneType, List[NoneType]]
):
    assert type(x) in [int, list, str, dict, list]
    if type(x) == int:
        assert x >= 0 and x <= 10
    if type(x) == list:
        assert all([el is None for el in x])
    if type(x) == dict:
        for k, v in x.items():
            assert k is None
            assert type(v) == list
            for el in v:
                assert el is None
```

Python gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'Int' and 'List'
```

This seems to be because `Int[0,10]` has the type of its class `pybt.typing.Int`, not `type`. However, using `typing.Union` works just fine.

```
def test_handles_none_with_arged_types(
    x: Union[Int[0, 10], List[Int], Str, Dict[NoneType, List[NoneType]]]
):
    ...
```

Is there a way to get around this? Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to hold off instantiating `Int` or other types that are indexed in their `__class_getitem__` under.

EDIT:

Here is the full class (for List):

```
class List:
    def __init__(self, sub_type=_DEFAULT_SUB_TYPE, max_len=_DEFAULT_MAX_LEN):
        self.max_len: int = _DEFAULT_MAX_LEN
        self.sub_type = sub_type
        if max_len is not None:
            self.max_len = max_len

    def __str__(self):
        return "pybt.types.List"

    def __class_getitem__(cls, parameters):
        sub_type = None
        max_len = None
        if type(parameters) != tuple:
            parameters = (parameters,)

        if len(parameters) > 2:
            raise TypeError("Expected 2 arguments: List[sub_type, max_length]")
        if len(parameters):
            sub_type = parameters[0]
        if len(parameters) > 1:
            max_len = parameters[1]

        if max_len and max_len <= 0:
            raise TypeError(f"Max Length of {cls.max_len} is less than or equal to 0")

        return cls(sub_type, max_len)
```

Comment: What version of Python, and what does the typing for `pybt.typing.Int` look like?  If you're using an older version of Python, I wouldn't be surprised if a quick upgrade is all you need to fix it.

Comment: This is Python 3.11.2. I'm not sure I understand your second question. Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Specifically, does `Int` subclass `typing.Generic`, or some other subscriptable type?  I'm not sure offhand exactly how that works at runtime with the `|` operator but it's generally a requirement for type checking so I assume it might be relevant here.

Comment: Ah, no it does not subclass typing.Generic. It is its own class.

Comment: See my edit for the class definition...

Comment: this is really strange, why is is `__class_getitem__` instantiating the class!?

Comment: " that have generators on them." what do you mean by "generators"? " I am using this to fuzz the function based on the type annotations. " what does this mean??

Comment: `assert type(x) in [int, list, str, dict, list]` will not pass for your types....

Comment: "This seems to be because Int[0,10] has the type of its class pybt.typing.Int, not type. However, using typing.Union works just " Of course, because `Union` doesn't require any special method to work. You can provide *anything you want*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know about dunder methods and `type`, so apologies if this answer restates the obvious to you.

For `Int() | List()` to work (or anything that creates instances, like your `List[]`), there must be either a `Int.__or__` or a `List.__ror__`, or both.

This works with the classes, as in `Int | List`, because `type` itself implements both `__or__` and `__ror__`:

```
>>> type.__or__
<slot wrapper '__or__' of 'type' objects>
```

So try adding the following methods to your classes:

```
from typing import Union

class List:
    ...
    def __or__(self, other):
        return Union[self, other]
    def __ror__(self, other):
        return Union[self, other]
```

Seems to play well with other types, even its own class:

```
>>> List() | List
typing.Union[<__main__.List object at 0x0000024A7F7F93D0>, __main__.List]
```

Comment: Doh! No, it doesn't restate the obvious. I totally missed that. Thank you!

Comment: I think you'd want to put the `__or__` implementation on a metaclass. Otherwise you risk overriding the desired behaviour of classes that already have an implementation for the `|` operator - such as ints and sets. That is, you want `Set() | Set([1, 2])` to equal `Set([1, 2])` and not  `Union[Set(), Set([1, 2])]`.

Comment: This is all totally wrong, you shouldn't be implementing `__or__` on the class to support using the class in a union for a type annotation

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, this is exactly what the _GenericAlias class in the python typing module does. This is exactly what you need to do...

Comment: @dvr my point is that you shouldn't be doing this. Why are you defining something to act like the generic alias type?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, because I am writing a framework that generates random arguments for a given function. To do this, I inspect the function signature and use the type annotations to generate the arguments. Originally I did this with python types but I found it was easier to implement if I wrote my own classes, each with a `generate` method responsible for generating a variable of the correct type.

Comment: As for your comment above, I agree that it is strange that the `__class_getitem__` dunder instantiates the class. One way I could fix this is to have an alias for each type I implement. I could also just use the `__init__` directly. However, I do like the fact that I can syntax like `List[Int | Str]`. The args you are seeing in `Int` are to "specialize" the argument generated. For example `Int[0,10]` means the argument generated will be an integer between 0 and 10.

Comment: I would welcome and appreciate your thoughts on how to do this!

Comment: @dvr this makes a lot more sense, please consider being a bit more explicit about this sort of context. I'll note, you probably shouldn't be using `__class_getitem__`, it's use is "discouraged". Furthermore, you should probably be using check out [PEP 593](https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/) if you want to create your own annotations for runtime use, and have them be compatible with static analysis tools! Otherwise, you are just creating *incorrect annotations* from the POV of static analysis tools like mypy, pyright

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253322/discussion-between-dvr-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).